# Android OS 6.0.1 Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x, crash-reports

I got this error when I tried starting the app through Samsung S7 edge. I have tried running the app on other devices with OS 5.1 and below, and the app worked fine. Here is the error I get from Google console:

```
Build fingerprint:
'samsung/hero2ltexx/hero2lte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G935FXXS1APG2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '9'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 30659, tid: 30659, name: iplay.jaeger >>> com.roshanstudio.jaeger<<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfa18081c
    r0 da180818  r1 f727adf0  r2 00000001  r3 ffffffff
    r4 07ffffff  r5 da180820  r6 0000001f  r7 00000000
    r8 f727ae0c  r9 40000003  sl 00000001  fp f727a920
    ip f4d80fb0  sp ffb4d738  lr f7243703  pc f7241938  cpsr 20070030

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00049938  /system/lib/libc.so (arena_run_reg_alloc+87)
    #01 pc 0004b6ff  /system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_tcache_fill_small+94)
    #02 pc 0005ca3b  /system/lib/libc.so (je_tcache_alloc_small_hard+18)
    #03 pc 0005752d  /system/lib/libc.so (je_malloc+1112)
    #04 pc 000487f1  /system/lib/libc++.so (_Znwj+16)
    #05 pc 000807a7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #06 pc 0316fbd1  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x2f36000)
```

fyi: this app using cocos2dx 3.8 as platform